# does solr optimize storing of frequently repeated field values cross documents?

Tags: indexing, solr

Our setup is like this. We emulate what is traditionally understood as a relational database (with one to many connections between entities) by having two SOLR indices. One of them (A) stores documents with fields logically attributed to every document in the other (B). Not only we establish a relation, but also (I believe) save indices from growing unnecessary.

As of current moment we are evaluating merging both indices such that every field of document(id=i) in A will be copied to every document(foreign_key=i) of B. After that A is not needed anymore.

My question is: does SOLR optimize storing frequently repeated values in the entire index? Will merging in such a scenario cause B to bloat?

The one to many relation from A to B has in average 10k links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that after moving the fields from A to B, B grew by less than one percent, which implies that Solr does some optimization in storing frequently used field values.